# Laravel relationship design

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm working on team management project.
I have a problem with doing relationships.

I want to display users in boards, but also want to look good and easy to read. I already designed relationships but when I saw JSON output of relationships, it was completely messed.

Is there some way how to display relationship data this way?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name: "Test",
    "members": [
        {
            ... user model here
            "name": "Peter",
            "email": "peter@peter.com",
        }
    ]
}
```

My migrations:

Boards migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBoardsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('boards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('boards');
    }
}
```

Membership migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMembershipsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('memberships', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('board_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('memberships');
    }
```

}

EDIT:

Models

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Board extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function members() {
        return $this->hasMany(Membership::class)->with('user');
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Membership extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['board_id', 'user_id'];
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us where you set up the relations, aka `belongsTo`, `hasOne`, `hasMany` etc.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you talking about [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) members with boards? `Board::with('members')->get()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to define the relationships in the models as a Many to Many one, i.e.:

```
class User
{    
    public function boards()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Board', 'memberships', 'user_id', 'board_id');
    }
}

class Board
{    
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'memberships', 'board_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

With that relations defined you don't really need a Membership Model if it has not additional fields, and you can write code like that:

```
User::find($id)->boards
Board::find($id)->members
Board::with('members')->find($id)
```

You could read also the documentation on [Many to Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: This is not exactly what I want, JSON I am getting looks like this https://pastebin.com/mrJ6BgZg

Comment: That JSON is the result of `App\Board::with('members')->get();`?

Comment: No, JSON result of `$board->members;`

Comment: please try `App\Board::with('members')->get();` or `App\Board::with('members')->find($id);`

Comment: IMHO its look like the result of your relations, not the ones I posted